# JS map to translate values back and forth

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach mapping values back and forward as a sort of translation process. The use case is having to process a non SEO friendly attribute code into a nicer format and display that on the frontend, but i also need to be able to process the nice attribute label back into original code so i can use that in my script. In the following example, i'd want to be able to look up `myMap` to check if a string value exists in the object, and if it does, pull out its corresponding label.

```
        var myString =  'color_attr_code'; // Want to be able to extract 'color' from the map
        var myAltString =  'color'; // Want to be able to extract 'color_attr_code'

        var myMap = {
            'color_attr_code': 'color'
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, what exactly is stopping you from adding the inverse [key,value] pair into `myMap` (or even into a separate object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, though in modern environments you might use a `Map` rather than an object, or at least create the object without a prototype so there aren't false matches on `toString` or `valueOf` or other things the default object prototype provides.

You'd have *two* maps, one going each direction, probably best derived from the same source data:

```
const mappings = [
    ["color_attr_code", "color"],
    ["blah_attr_code", "blah"],
    // ...
];
const attrToLabel = new Map(mappings);
const labelToAttr = new Map(mappings.map(([key, value]) => [value, key]));
```

Then you use `attrToLabel.get("color_attr_code")` to get the corresponding label, and `labelToAttr.get("color")` to get the corresponding code.

Live Example:

```js
const mappings = [
    ["color_attr_code", "color"],
    ["blah_attr_code", "blah"],
    // ...
];
const attrToLabel = new Map(mappings);
const labelToAttr = new Map(mappings.map(([key, value]) => [value, key]));

console.log(`Label for "color_attr_code": ${attrToLabel.get("color_attr_code")}`);
console.log(`Code for "color": ${labelToAttr.get("color")}`);
```

Or in ES5 (although really, in today's world, there's no reason to write ES5 manually — write modern code and transpile with Babel or similar) and objects:

```
var mappings = [
    ["color_attr_code", "color"],
    ["blah_attr_code", "blah"],
    // ...
];
var attrToLabel = Object.create(null);
var labelToAttr = Object.create(null);
mappings.forEach(function(mapping) {
    var code = mapping[0], label = mapping[1];
    attrToLabel[code] = label;
    labelToAttr[label] = code;
});
```

Then you use `attrToLabel["color_attr_code"]` to get the corresponding label, and `labelToAttr["color"]` to get the corresponding code.

---

Of course, all of this assumes there are always just 1:1 mappings, that there aren't (for instance) two codes that both map to the same label.